# said something to offend you

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> *Look, I'm really sorry if we've said something **to** offend you.*

"*...said something **to** offend you.*" seems to be the standard phrase, but does it mean:

"I'm really sorry if we've said something that offended you."

or

"I'm really sorry if we've said something with the purpose of offending you. We shouldn't have."

Comment: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=said+something+that+upset+you%2Csaid+something+to+upset+you%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaid%20something%20that%20upset%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaid%20something%20to%20upset%20you%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csaid%20something%20that%20upset%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csaid%20something%20to%20upset%20you%3B%2Cc0) showing that *[I'm sorry if I] said something **to** upset you* is far more common than *...said something **that** upset you* (even though in almost all cases the meaning will be identical).

Comment: (That's to say, it would be perverse to interpret ***to*** there as meaning ***in order to** [deliberately achieve some outcome]*. It's just the idiomatically establish phrasing for the "apologetic" context.)

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is the correct understanding. People don't usually set out to offend others and then apologize for it; the apology is for accidentally (unknowingly) offending.